# Does MySQL LIMT not working may have some to do with table structure?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL query working on machine #1 but not on the #2.

The query is:

```
SELECT
id, vehicle
FROM
requests
WHERE client_id = 8
AND
solved
IS NULL
AND requests_id IS NULL ORDER BY created
DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
```

If I take out `LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10` it does work.

I'm wondering if could be something with table's config but I have checked twice and they are basically the same on both servers...

Comment: Are you sure you have more then 10 rows?

Comment: @scaisEdge well I cleaned the table but I have 2 entries. I also tested with LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1 and it does't work anyway...

Comment: what are the differences between #1 and #2?

Comment: So, You have more than 20 records. Correct?

Comment: Sorry guys, just found out I haven't more than 10 entries. So that mean OFFSET won't paginate except you have that number of results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you concluded & asked the same

> Sorry guys, just found out I haven't more than 10 entries. So that
>   mean OFFSET won't paginate except you have that number of results?  ~ **@Filipe**

***Quick Start***

- [PHP Limit Data Selections From MySQL](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp)
- [LIMIT and OFFSET SQL Pagination](https://www.petefreitag.com/item/451.cfm)

***Examples***

**1)** `$sql = "SELECT * FROM TableName LIMIT 20";`

=> Will will return the first 20 records.

**2)** `$sql = "SELECT * FROM TableName LIMIT 10 OFFSET 15";`

Or

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM TableName LIMIT 15, 10";
```

=> Will return only 10 records, start on record 16 (OFFSET 15)